# What alternatives can I use instead of GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query as follows

```
SELECT
substances.id,
substances.`name`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cas.`value`) SEPARATOR "<br>") AS cas_number,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ecs.`value`) SEPARATOR "<br>") AS ec_number
FROM
substances
LEFT JOIN ecs_substances
ON substances.id = ecs_substances.substance_id 
LEFT JOIN ecs
ON ecs_substances.ec_id = ecs.id 
LEFT JOIN cas_substances
ON cas_substances.substance_id = substances.id 
LEFT JOIN cas
ON cas_substances.cas_id = cas.id
```

This goes through a table of chemical substances (`substances`) which contains approx 250,000 rows.

It then references tables for the EC (`ec.value`) and CAS (`cas.value`) numbers (these are chemical terms) for those substances. There are also tables which are used as a reference to say which substances belong to which EC and CAS numbers, `ec_substances` and `cas_substances` respectively.

The problem I have is that one substance can have multiple EC and CAS numbers. The query I have takes care of this by getting each substance into 1 row, and then providing a separated list of the EC and CAS numbers - the separator is `<br>` because it's output in a PHP web application.

The query is slow, and I believe it's due to using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The following query is about 15 times quicker to run. However, this puts EC and CAS numbers on their own individual rows; so substance rows (`substance.id` and `substance.name`) are duplicated where multiple EC and CAS exist for that substance.

```
SELECT
substances.id,
substances.`name`,
ecs.`value` AS ec_number,
cas.`value` AS cas_number
FROM
ecs_substances
JOIN substances
ON ecs_substances.substance_id = substances.id 
JOIN ecs
ON ecs_substances.ec_id = ecs.id 
JOIN cas_substances
ON cas_substances.substance_id = substances.id 
JOIN cas
ON cas_substances.cas_id = cas.id
```

Are there any "middle ground" options which will still provide the EC and CAS numbers on one row, but without the overhead of using `GROUP_CONCAT`?

The application is running in PHP but ideally I want a MySQL-only solution because I believe it is faster to get the results in this way than post process them in PHP.

Comment: Please read this, especially the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/   Have you tried eliminating the `DISTINCT` item inside the `GROUP_CONCAT()` calls?  Your two queries are *very* different -- one uses `LEFT JOIN` and the other uses `JOIN`.  Queries with `LEFT JOIN` can generate much larger result sets.

Comment: Yes string operations may overwhelm SQL engines. I would do this concat operation in php, since SQL doesn't do anything after it generates the concated string.

Comment: There is no real alternative to group_concat() in MySQL. I would go down the php route as well. (It's interesting, though, that you said you wanted an sql solution, yet you tagged your question with php. If you do not want a php solution, then why tag your question with that?)

Comment: @Shadow - I mentioned PHP because the application is built in PHP/MySQL. If using a PHP approach is better, then I'm very interested in that. I also figured someone with experiencing of building PHP/MySQL applications may have come across this problem before. On the face of the comments here, there's not much that can be done in SQL other than eliminating `DISTINCT` and possibly letting something else (such as PHP!) handle the string manipulation. Incidentally, removing `DISTINCT` gives different (i.e. the wrong) results.